# Ошибка импорта базы данных с более новой версии MySQL

Tags: mysql, python, innodb, импорт, dump

Возникла проблема при импорте с MySQL 5.7.15 на версию 5.5.52. 
На своем рабочем компе сделал проект основанном на Django 1.10.2, а когда дело дошло до переноса базы данных на боевой сервер, вываливается ошибка.

Ошибка в консоли:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 105: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(150' at line 4
```

Ошибка в phpMyAdmin:

```
Ошибка
SQL-запрос:

CREATE TABLE  `auth_user` (

 `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `password` VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,
 `last_login` DATETIME( 6 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `is_superuser` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
 `username` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL ,
 `first_name` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `last_name` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 254 ) NOT NULL ,
 `is_staff` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
 `is_active` TINYINT( 1 ) NOT NULL ,
 `date_joined` DATETIME( 6 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `username` (  `username` )
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT =2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(150' at line 4
```

На моем компе установлены:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

на сервере:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Кодировка файла бекапа UTF8, кодировка баз данных utf8_general_ci, движок/тип InnoDB. 
Пробовал играться с кодировками, заливать через консоль, phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench ну и другие режимы совместимости, в общем из этого ничего хорошего не вышло. Конечно когда БД небольшая тогда можно создать пустую БД на сервере и в ручную перенести данные. Но когда например интернет магазин то тогда выходит не зальешь на сервер с более новой версии MySQL на старую.
Кто сталкивался и у кого есть решения как справиться с этой проблемой отпишитесь, может быть она простая, но что-то не доходит или чего то не замечаю что есть очевидным скорее из-за своей не опытности. За ранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вы бы запрос бы привели полностью какой выполняеться?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я добавил кроме ошибки с консоли, ошибку с запросом в phpMyAdmin

Comment: У строки last_login попробуйте слово DEFAULT убрать.

Comment: Не помогло, я сравнил эти строки с более старым python/Django проектом, они одинаковы, все равно та же ошибка. Обратный импорт того же дампа в MySQL 5.7.15 нормально проходит, уже в более старый MySQL 5.5.52 нет.

Comment: тогда слово NULL то же уберите и у datetime 6 в скобочках. вообще не понимаю что она значит. т.е. оставьте в этой строке `last_login DATETIME,`

Comment: Тоже в том же месте ошибка, я сравнил куски кода дампов с разных проектов. Тут я так понимаю что немного другой синтаксис у более новой версии MeSQL и старая его не понимает

Comment: Подержка точности DATETIME была добавлена в MySQL 5.6.4 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть, пробовать где ее в ручную удалить. А вообще существуют какие-нибудь конвертеры или утилиты для обратной миграции чтобы не редактировать записи в ручную?